# Problems in the AndroidManifest.xml after compiling APK with Buildozer (Signing apk in androidstudio)

Tags: android-studio, kivy, apk, android-manifest, buildozer

I'm having some trouble signing my APK (in android studio) that I made with buildozer. The app works perfectly in the 2 devices y tested. The problem is that Android Studio show the androidmanifest.xlm with the following problems:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="7211"
    android:versionName="0.1"
    android:installLocation="0"
    package="org.jpproductions.covdate">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="27" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x20000" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:theme="@ref/0x01030006"
        android:label="@ref/0x7f040000"
        android:icon="@ref/0x7f010001"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="wakelock"
            android:value="0" />

        <activity
            android:label="@ref/0x7f040000"
            android:name="org.kivy.android.PythonActivity"
            android:launchMode="2"
            android:screenOrientation="1"
            android:configChanges="0x40002fff">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I dont have control over the manifest. and android studio cant sign my apk for problems in parts of the manifest like the folowing:

```
    android:installLocation="0",
    android:glEsVersion="0x20000"
    android:theme="@ref/0x01030006"
    android:label="@ref/0x7f040000"
    android:icon="@ref/0x7f010001",
    android:label="@ref/0x7f040000",
    android:configChanges="0x40002fff">
```

The Errors in Android studio:

```
Error:(2, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [covdate-0.1-armeabi-v7a-release-unsigned] /Users/josepablo/ApkProjects/covdate-0.1-armeabi-v7a-release-unsigned/AndroidManifest.xml:2: error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'installLocation' with value '0').
Error:(29, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [covdate-0.1-armeabi-v7a-release-unsigned] /Users/josepablo/ApkProjects/covdate-0.1-armeabi-v7a-release-unsigned/AndroidManifest.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@ref/0x01030006').
Error:(29, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [covdate-0.1-armeabi-v7a-release-unsigned] /Users/josepablo/ApkProjects/covdate-0.1-armeabi-v7a-release-unsigned/AndroidManifest.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@ref/0x7f040000').
    <application
Error:(40, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [covdate-0.1-armeabi-v7a-release-unsigned] /Users/josepablo/ApkProjects/covdate-0.1-armeabi-v7a-release-unsigned/AndroidManifest.xml:40: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@ref/0x7f040000').
Error:(40, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [covdate-0.1-armeabi-v7a-release-unsigned] /Users/josepablo/ApkProjects/covdate-0.1-armeabi-v7a-release-unsigned/AndroidManifest.xml:40: error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'launchMode' with value '2').
Error:(40, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [covdate-0.1-armeabi-v7a-release-unsigned] /Users/josepablo/ApkProjects/covdate-0.1-armeabi-v7a-release-unsigned/AndroidManifest.xml:40: error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'screenOrientation' with value '1').
Error:(40, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [covdate-0.1-armeabi-v7a-release-unsigned] /Users/josepablo/ApkProjects/covdate-0.1-armeabi-v7a-release-unsigned/AndroidManifest.xml:40: error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value '0x40002fff').
```

I'm realy lost any help will be greatly appreciated

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not clear, what problems does it show? Also, does it work if you sign the apk using the command line tools without android studio?

Comment: y will put the probllems that android studio show.

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this, How can i sign the APK with the command line. Thank you very much

Comment: See the [apksigner documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner). You might also need `zipalign`.